# Difficulty in finding correct xpath in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am doing Data Integration task where I am reading the data from Excel and comparing with UI for a number of patients. Finding difficulty to read one of the field from UI. As shown in image [![ https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZtrs.png]
for a particular patient 3 rows displayed it can be different number of rows for each patient.It can be between 2 to 5. I wanted to fetch the value whose been ticked with checkbox, as per image I
wanted to fetch the value '1902802952'.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 116px;" xpath="1">
    <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 99px; width: 780px;">
        <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px"></div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px"></div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row active even" style="top:50px">
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3 active">
            1902802952
            </div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l4 r4"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l5 r5"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l6 r6">
                <input id="chk-attributed-provider-ind-19879" type="checkbox" class="chk-attributed-provider-ind" checked="checked" onchange="AttributedProviderIndChange(this,'19879','1652168');">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
            <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with following code which is not right way and also giving an error.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='PatientAssignedProvidersGridContainer']/div[5]/div/div")
List<WebElement> npiList;
    if(npiList.size()==2)
    {
        WebElement npi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='PatientAssignedProvidersGridContainer']/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3']"));
        String NPI = npi.getText();
        int NPIValue = Integer.parseInt(NPI.trim());
    }

    if(npiList1.size()==3)
    {
        WebElement npi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='PatientAssignedProvidersGridContainer']/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3']"));
        String NPI = npi.getText();
        int NPIValue = Integer.parseInt(NPI.trim());
    }
```

Above code some time get execute successfully and some time giving an error for same patient. 'java.lang.Number FormatException: For Input string:"".

The another i tried is

```
//input[@class='chk-attributed-provider-ind'][@checked='checked'][@type='checkbox']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3'] but giving 0 element.
```

As input and div are not sibling but parent of input tag is sibling of div tag but don't know how to write xpath for it.
Any help will be appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any IDE that you could help you debug and can utilize breakpoints so you could step through the code?

Try (at least for debugging purposes) use **full_xpath**. Usually the correct full-XPath is available from Chrome browser:
**Right click on the value** you're trying to get the selector for.
**Click Inspect**
**With this value selected**, **right click** in the highlighted area of the inspection panel that opened, **go to Copy->Copy full XPath**: [image]
Generally try avoiding using full_xpath as it is prone to go out of sync with smallest webpage structure changes, but for debugging - it is a great resource).

**EDIT 2:**
Just realized I can't edit my comments, but only my answer, so I'm going to reply in this section.

One thing I noticed that you're using Java, but the logic shouldn't be much different from python, which I'm more familiar with.
First question, and I know, this is more about optimization, but why are you referring to driver again when you selected the parent selector already?
WebElement npi = **driver**.findElement?
Use:

```
WebElement npi = npiList.findElement(...
```

second part is, your npiList holds entire structure of all of your elements, including checkboxes, etc. Loop through each element until you you come across the one that is **checked='checked'**. (here you have to reference syntax for java, sorry but this part I'm not familiar).

Final suggestion, try:

```
@class='custom-tooltip'
```

instead of:

```
@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell ...
```

At least in Python, just use 1class-name, the above reference works, especially if you narrow down to sub elements of one selector, and not the entire page.

Please post your findings here.

Comment: Your suggestion will give me a solution but again its same as i mentioned above with if condition,  for 2,3,4 rows different path will get.  I think for one path solution need to correct this path "//input[@class='chk-attributed-provider-ind'][@checked='checked'][@type='checkbox']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3'] " will give a correct solution.

Comment: for that you could probably: all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(...) and then loop until len(element.text) > 0

Comment: please check for my EDIT 2 part of my answer for some additional details.

Comment: What you suggested, i try it and let you know soon. Thanks.

Comment: i tried with following code : int size = npiList.size();
 System.out.println("npisize:-" + size);
 String npi = npiList.get(size).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3 active']")).getText();
 System.out.println("New npi:- " +npi); Showing correct size but giving error Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index2, size2.  I missed on working checked='checked'. I modified and can try again.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but found partial solution, WebElement npi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='chk-attributed-provider-ind'][@checked='checked']/parent::*/[preceding-sibling::div[3] | /parent::*/[following-sibling::div[3]]")); but 'OR' condition is not working. Individual preceding and following are working fine.